# Outlook social connector not showing SharePoint updates

Tags: outlook, social-connector

I'm trying to set up Outlook 2010's social connector to work with SharePoint 2010. While I can import SharePoint contacts, I can't get status updates to show in the People Pane. I've posted a similar note in various Microsoft forums and even have a paid-ticket open with them. I'm not getting too far. Maybe someone here can help?

Here's my configuration:

Server A: Win Server 2008 x64 w/SP2, Exchange 2010 x64, domain controller
Server B: Win Server 2008 x64 w/SP2, domain member, SQL Server 2008 R2, SharePoint 2010
Client: Win 7, domain member, with Office 2010 RTM (most every component installed, including the OSC)

I've added my domain users to a group. In SharePoint, I added that group to the Home Members group, giving my users Contribute permissions. Since then, I've also added a couple of users to the Home Group directly, and assigned the Design permission. As any of the domain users, I can use IE to log on the My Sites pages. From there, I can add lists, blog posts, status updates etc.

In Outlook, below a contact's picture I click Add and enter in my login details for my SharePoint account and it seems to work. I can add a SharePoint contact to my Contacts list. I can publish my Outlook calendar to SharePoint. But, all I see in the People Pane is emails my users have exchanged. I don't see any of the other SharePoint status updates.

When I try to use the "Add this person to My Sites" link to connect them with my SharePoint account, the process fails. Outlook briefly shows the blue "i" over the My Sites icon in the People Pane. During that time, the tooltip says it's waiting for confirmation from the SharePoint user. But, then it goes to a red-X with the tooltip saying "Error adding this person on My Site. Click for more options." Clicking gives me a "Try Again" button that likewise fails and a Cancel button, which removes the My Site icon altogether.

In SharePoint Central, I had an error message that the Activity Feed Timer Job was not running. That message directed me to create a claims-based site & site collection. I did. I enabled the Activity Feed Timer Job and manually ran it. No change on the client side. I still can't get status updates in Outlook. I restarted the SharePoint server and client, still no status updates.

Comment: Updates: MS support helped me determine that installed SharePoint in Standalone configuration. I had to reinstall in Farm / Complete mode. I can connect w/in Outlook to My Sites--I don't get the red-x over the My Sites icon any more. But I'm still not seeing updates in the People Pane.

Comment: Getting closer. Re-added the Activity Feed Timer Job (forgot to do that after reinstalling). Then, enabled outgoing SMTP. I now see "user A added a new colleague" in the People Pane. But still no other status updates, profile info, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working now. The comments above give the gist of what it took to get the updates flowing. The final "problem" was impatience. The Activity Feed Timer Job is scheduled to run once per hour by default. I simply had not waited long enough for it to run and thus was not seeing updates when I posted the second comment above.

So, the basic summary is:

1. Install SQL Server using the SharePoint template
2. Install SharePoint into a new farm, using the complete method -- not Standalone mode
3. Configure AD synchronization

   1. Start the Profile Sync Service
   2. Application management>Manage Service Application>User Profile Service Application then click Configure Synchronization Connections.
   3. Create a new connection
   4. Click Populate containers, then select the container/ou to synchronize
   5. Application Management>Manage Service Application> User Profile Service Application, then click Start Profile Synchronization
   6. Wait
4. Grant appropriate permissions to the users to the site
5. Configure outgoing SMTP (see http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-outgoing-email-sharepoint-2010/)
6. Add/enable the Activity Feed Timer job (and set a reasonable schedule)

   1. Monitoring>Review Job Definitions
   2. Click User Profile Service Applications
   3. Adjust the schedule, if you want, then click Enable

Comment: From reading your overview I thought you had checked it in the portal and that it just wasn't making it to Outlook.  Congrats on figuring it out, I know this took many by surprise when it was in Beta review.  I expect this post to see some interest over time.

Comment: The Microsoft SharePoint tech I was working with stated that the OSC is supposed to work with SharePoint in a standalone installation configuration. He said to expect a patch or update in the future to make it work. So, I guess I wasn't that far off-base in attempting a Standalone configuration.

Status updates take over an hour to show up, even with the Activity Feed Timer job set to run every 5 mins. The MS tech had no advice on how to make updates show up more quickly.

Comment: Further discussions with MS tech support...they say the default update interval is 60 minutes. But, you can set it by updating or adding the following registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\policies\microsoft\office\outlook\socialconnector

DWORD: ActivitySyncInterval

Value: an integer between 1 and 10080  (default is 60 minutes if DWORD is missing)

It controls how frequently activity feed information is synchronized between Outlook and connected social networks (in minutes).

Comment: Your summary did not specify whether claims-based authentication setup was required? In your final solution, "was claims-based authentication setup required?" -thanks, Jonathan Oien